# Reference_wrapper: Push_back works but not assigning

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, reference-wrapper

In the following code, `push_back()` a `std::ref` into a `std::vector<reference_wrapper<Type>>` works well however, assigning a `std::ref` to a `reference_wrapper<Type>` does not work. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct Type {};

int main()
{
    Type t1;

    vector<reference_wrapper<Type>> t2;
    t2.push_back( ref(t1) ); // OK

    //reference_wrapper<Type> t3; // error: no matching function for call to std::reference_wrapper<Type>::reference_wrapper()’
    //t3 = ref(t1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to default construct a reference wrapper, what exactly would it be referring to if that was allowed? And the title of your question has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Why not `reference_wrapper<Type> t3 = ref(t1);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you that the actual problem is that a reference wrapper has no default constructor. You *can* assign one reference wrapper to another, but you can't make an "empty" reference wrapper first and *then* give it a value through assignment.

Answer (score 2):

reference_wrapper as it follows from its name shall reference some object. So it has no the default constructor.